# Зависание цикла requests

Tags: python, python-3.x, requests

Такая проблема: есть бесконечный цикл while True, который через определенный промежуток времени отправляет get запрос через requests. скрипт упакован pyinstaller в ехе. Скрипт работает прекрасно, но через какое то время (час, два, день) запросы просто останавливаются, без except, просто стоят как будто окно консоли зависло. В чем может быть проблема? Куда копать? И как сделать скрипт стабильнее(try-except не помогло)? Сам код простой, вот пример:

```
import requests
import time
while True:
    r = requests.get ('mysite.com')
    t = time.sleep (5)
```

Comment: Вы пробовали запускать этот же скрипт вне экзешника?

Comment: @hedgehogues да так же работает, но вне ехе долго не тестил, зависает скрипт то не сразу, можно ждать час, а можно день. а что может pyinstaller глючить?

Comment: Может быть всё, что угодно. Попробуйте запустить вне экзешника. Процесс запускаете один?

Comment: Вы ходите на какой-то конкретный сайт или к себе на сервер? Если первое, то вполне возможно, что Вас просто лочат из-за того, что вы становитесь похожи на бота (собственно, вы и есть бот)

Comment: @hedgehogues процесс один, блокируют вряд ли, сайт простейший и запросов я делаю не так много (задержку 5с указал для примера). вне ехе не очень удобно, так как запускаю на компьютере где не установлен python и поставить нет возможности

Comment: Ох... Странно. Ладно. Стартану сейчас у себя. До вечера. Поглядим.

Comment: Сайт укажите. Иначе непонятно куда стучаться

Comment: Попробуйте под 2-м питоном. Может зайдёт. Но, лучше сайт дайте мне. Для чистоты эксперимента, попробую у себя.

Comment: Вы напишите? Эй!

Comment: Таймаут укажите?

Comment: @andreymal вроде бы указан. Не ? t = time.sleep (5)

Comment: @hedgehogues это пауза между запросами, а не таймаут у самого запроса

Comment: @andreymal я если честно не в курсе как указывать в requests тайм-аут. а если он вышел, это как то повлияет на работу цикла?

Comment: @hedgehogues сайт к сожалению не могу назвать, но банов, капчи и прочих репрессий я там не наблюдал

Comment: @andreymal какая разница?

Comment: @ИгорьЖданов почему Вы не допускаете, что словили именно бан?

Comment: @ИгорьЖданов как-то так: `requests.get('mysite.com', timeout=30)` Скорее всего, скрипт останавливается из-за случайно подвиснувшего интернета, и если я прав, то с таймаутом вместо зависания вылетит ошибка по истечении этого самого таймаута (30 секунд в данном примере), а эту ошибку уже можно будет потом отловить через try-except

Comment: @andreymal спасибо сейчас потестим!

Comment: @andreymal, кстати у меня похожая проблема, и таймаут не спасает (какое-то время работает, потом на реквесте зависает, несмотря на таймаут), приходится вручную прибивать и перезапускать скрипт. Думаю в отдельный поток/процесс засунуть, а из второго потока/процесса прибивать, если перестает отвечать. Но пока лень.

Answer (score 0):

Во первых попытайтесь выяснить ошибку (exception) которую выбивает Python, но скорее всего как написали в ответах вас просто лочат из-за того что вы ведете себя как бот, в данном случае можно поставить реквест в експшн и ждать какое-нибудь время, пока блокировка не пройдет, да и ошибку желательно все таки узнать.

Узнате - пишите опять)

```
import requests
import time
while True:
    try:
       r = requests.get ('mysite.com')
    except Exception:
       time.sleep(500)
    t = time.sleep (5)
```

Comment: `sleep` в `except` неизвестно откуда появился, нужно через time вызывать либо из time импортировать, плюс `t =` не нужно -- `sleep` всегда возвращает `None`. Да и время в 500 секунд вызывает вопросы, почему ожидание именно 8 минут и 20 секунд? :) Круглые даты по мне меньше вызывают вопросов, например: 5 минут или 10 минут

Answer (score 0):

В `self.timeout_*` перечислены варианты остановки по таймауту, и дельнейшего продолжения работы

```
import multiprocessing, requests, queue

class Requests:
    def __init__(self, url, timeout_retry, timeout_connect, timeout_read, timeout_break, ):
        self.url = url

        self.process = None
        self.process_out = multiprocessing.Queue()

        self.exit_event = multiprocessing.Event()
        self.stop = self.exit_event.set

        self.timeout_retry = timeout_retry  # сколько секунд будет ждать клиент, перед повторным запросом url серверу
        self.timeout_connect = timeout_connect  # сколько секунд будет ждать клиент, чтобы установить первоначальное соединение с сервером
        self.timeout_read = timeout_read  # сколько секунд будет ждать клиент, между пакетами, отправленными сервером
        self.timeout_break = timeout_break  # сколько секунд будет ждать клиент, скачивания всех пакетов ответа сервера

    def start_circle(self):
        self._new_process()
        while not self.exit_event.is_set():
            try:
                yield self.process_out.get(timeout=self.timeout_break)
            except queue.Empty:
                if self.process.is_alive():
                    self.process.terminate()
                self._new_process()

    def _run(self):
        while not self.exit_event.is_set():
            try:
                req = requests.get(self.url, timeout=(self.timeout_connect, self.timeout_read))
            except (requests.ConnectionError, requests.Timeout):
                continue
            else:
                self.process_out.put(req.content)
                self.exit_event.wait(timeout=self.timeout_retry)

    def _new_process(self):
        self.process = multiprocessing.Process(target=self._run, daemon=True)
        self.process.start()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    r = Requests('http://ya.ru/', timeout_retry=5, timeout_connect=3, timeout_read=4, timeout_break=7)
    g = r.start_circle()
    for (count, content) in enumerate(g, start=1):
        print(count, content)
        if count == 2:
            r.stop()
```

1 b'<html class="...

2 b'<html class="...

Answer (score 0):

Я бы попробовал создать сессию и кидать запросы уже из нее, иначе соединения не закрываются и создаются постоянно новые. Возможно, пул соединений с какого-то момента начинает сбоить.

> The Session object allows you to persist certain parameters across requests. It also persists cookies across all requests made from the Session instance, and will use urllib3’s [connection pooling](https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/index.html#module-urllib3.connectionpool). So if you’re making several requests to the same host, the underlying TCP connection will be reused, which can result in a significant performance increase (see [HTTP persistent connection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_persistent_connection)).

Подробнее в оф. документации [requests](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/).